# Select rows from a database and sum/group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently struggling with the logic for this SQL Statement.

I have a single table with columns containing:

```
Country, Customer, Year, Product Purchased( 5 different products) and Revenue.
```

I'm looking to write a select statement that pulls through the Country, Customer Name, each Product Purchased, Revenue for each product for the customer in each year.

```
SELECT Country, Customer, Year, Product, Revenue
FROM table
GROUP BY Country, Customer, Year, Product Purchased, Revenue
```

Country Customer Year Product Revenue Total Revenue
England Customer A 2017 Product A 100 200
England Customer A 2017 Product B 100 200
England Customer A 2016 Product A 100 100
Can anyone help please?

Comment: I'm currently struggling with the way you've laid your requiremens out.. Why does `SELECT * FROM table` not fulfil your requrements?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired result.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sum(Revenue), Country, Customer, Year, Product
FROM table
GROUP BY Country, Customer, Year, Product
```

[Live demo to illustrate the result](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8f2b0/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(Revenue),Country, Customer, YEAR, Product 
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Country, Customer, YEAR, Product Purchased
```